# Format video to upload on instagram API (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to automate the process of posting photos and videos on instagram but I constantly get errors when uploading to instagram.

I will leave a video duration error here but several others happen, I need to follow the following requirements:

- Container: MOV or MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14), no edit lists, atom moov in front of file
- Audio codec: AAC, 48 kHz maximum sampling rate, 1 or 2 channel (mono or stereo)
- Video codec: HEVC or H.264, progressive scan, closed GOP, 4:2:0 chroma subsampling
- Frame rate: from 23 to 60 FPS
- photo size:

  - Maximum columns (horizontal pixels): 1,920
  - Minimum aspect ratio [columns/rows]: 4/5
  - Maximum aspect ratio [columns/rows]: 9/16
- Video bitrate: 5Mbps maximum VBR
- Audio bitrate: 128 kbps
- Duration: maximum 60 seconds and minimum 3 seconds
- File size: max 100 MB

My code:

```js
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import { IgApiClient } from 'instagram-private-api';
import fs from 'fs';

const s3 = new S3();
const ig = new IgApiClient();
const bucket = 'posts';
const { INSTA_USER, INSTA_PASS } = process.env;

ig.state.generateDevice(INSTA_USER);

export const main = async () => {
  try {
    await ig.account.login(INSTA_USER, INSTA_PASS);

    const { Contents } = await s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: bucket, MaxKeys: 2, Prefix: 'memes/geral' }).promise();

    const files = await Promise.all(Contents.map(async ({ Key }) => {
      const file = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key,
      }).promise();

      return file.Body;
    }));

    const publishResult = await ig.publish.video({
      video: files[0],
      coverImage: await fs.readFileAsync("../../src/assets/cover.png")
    });

    console.dir({ publishResult }, { depth: null })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

When I get a file from s3, it comes in the following format.
I'm taking the content of the body property and put it in the video property of the publish method.
Is it right?
I also tried to save the file with fs.writeFile and dps use readFileSync like in the example but it also gave the same error.

```
{
    AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
    LastModified: 2022-08-04T23:15:24.000Z,
    ContentLength: 3252472,
    ETag: '"c491cfe2fb5bc29777fc34391fc1d56a"',
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    Body: Buffer(3252472) [Uint8Array] [
        0,   0,   0,  32, 102, 116, 121, 112, 105, 115, 111, 109,
        0,   0,   2,   0, 105, 115, 111, 109, 105, 115, 111,  50,
       97, 118,  99,  49, 109, 112,  52,  49,   0,   0, 209,   0,
      109, 111, 111, 118,   0,   0,   0, 108, 109, 118, 104, 100,
        0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
        0,   0,   3, 232,   0,   0, 250,  17,   0,   1,   0,   0,
        1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
        0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
        0,   0,   0,   0,
      ... 3252372 more items
    ]
  }
```

Error:

```js
{
    "errorMessage": "POST /api/v1/media/upload_finish/?video=1 - 400 Bad Request; server processing error: VideoSourceDurationCheckException",
    "errorType": "IgUploadVideoError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "IgUploadVideoError: POST /api/v1/media/upload_finish/?video=1 - 400 Bad Request; server processing error: VideoSourceDurationCheckException",
        "    at C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\Insta\\.webpack\\service\\src\\functions\\webpack:\\instagram-private-api\\dist\\services\\publish.service.js:26:1",  
        "    at tryCatcher (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\Insta\\.webpack\\service\\src\\functions\\webpack:\\bluebird\\js\\release\\util.js:16:1)"
}
```

when I try to post a video under 60 seconds (apparently within the requirements):

```js
{
    "errorMessage": "POST /api/v1/media/configure/?video=1 - 403 Forbidden; ",
    "errorType": "IgConfigureVideoError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "IgConfigureVideoError: POST /api/v1/media/configure/?video=1 - 403 Forbidden; ",
        "    at PublishService.video (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\Insta\\.webpack\\service\\src\\functions\\webpack:\\instagram-private-api\\dist\\services\\publish.service.js:123:1)",        
        "    at C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\Insta\\.webpack\\service\\src\\functions\\webpack:\\src\\functions\\cronFreefireMemes.js:71:31",
        "    at async Promise.all (index 1)",
        "    at main (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\Insta\\.webpack\\service\\src\\functions\\webpack:\\src\\functions\\cronFreefireMemes.js:47:5)"
    ]
}
```

I know that the error above is happening because of the size of the video which is longer than 60 seconds.

But I would like to know if there is any way I can format any video to fit the instagram requirements.

Any nodejs library?

Comment: You could call ffmpeg using `node:child_process`'s exec or directly use the node library `fluent-ffmpeg`